# How to map floating number from sqlite db to TextInput and backward in React Native and redux?

Tags: react-native, redux, floating-point, android-sqlite, textinput

I'm getting a floating number from sqlite db and setting up it in redux state. Than I'm showing this property to TextInput component. To do this, I have to convert floating number to string. While editing value, I trigger event onChangeText, convert string to floating number and update redux state.

When I clear last char after point in a TextInput, my point also clearing because of converting property value from number to string. How can I save point in this case? And what's the wright way to work with floating values in react-redux?

My custom component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class FormFieldNumeric extends React.PureComponent {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            textValue: ''
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext) {
        if (parseFloat(this.state.textValue) !== nextProps.value) {
            this.setState({
                textValue: nextProps.value ? String(nextProps.value) : ''
            })
        }
    }

    onChangeText = text => {

        if (!text) {
            this.changeValue('');
            return;
        }

        if (text.length === 1) {
            if (!'0123456789'.includes(text)) {
                return;
            }
        }

        const lastSymbol = text[text.length - 1];
        if ('1234567890.,'.includes(lastSymbol)) {

            if (text.split('').filter(ch => ch === '.' || ch === ',').length > 1) {
                return;
            }

            if (lastSymbol === ',') {
                this.changeValue(this.state.textValue + '.');
                return;
            }

            this.changeValue(text);

        }

    };

    changeValue = text => {
        this.setState({
            textValue: text
        });
        this.props.onChange(text ? parseFloat(text) : 0);
    };

    render() {

        const { caption, value, onChange, placeholder } = this.props;

        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    value={this.state.textValue}
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    maxLength={10}
                />
            </View>
        )

    }
}

FormFieldNumeric.propType = {
    placeholder: PropTypes.string, 
    value: PropTypes.number, 
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default FormFieldNumeric;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understood what was my mistake. I fell into the anti-pattern trap when I try to keep the same state in two places. [This article](https://ru.reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html) describes in detail this. According to the recommendations from the article, I used an uncontrolled component and stored the state directly in the component, and I only pass the property in order to initialize the value.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class FormFieldNumeric extends React.PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            defaultValue: props.defaultValue,
            textValue: this.floatToTextValue(props.defaultValue)
        }
    }

    floatToTextValue = value => {
        return value ? String(value) : '';
    };

    render() {

        const { placeholder } = this.props;

        return (
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    value={this.state.textValue}
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                />
            </View>
        )

    }
}

FormFieldNumeric.defaultValue = {
    placeholder: '',
    defaultValue: 0
};

FormFieldNumeric.propType = {
    placeholder: PropTypes.string, 
    defaultValue: PropTypes.number, 
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default FormFieldNumeric;
```

And for the component to update the values ​​after loading the redux state, I made the _isLoading field in the parent component, which is true by default, but becomes false after the data is loaded. I passed this value as the key property of the parent component:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.PureComponent {

    _isLoading = false;

    async componentDidMount() {
        await this.props.onCreate();
        this._isLoading = false;
    }  

    render() {
        return (
            <View key={this._isLoading}>
                <FormFieldNumeric
                    defaultValue={this.props.cashSum}
                    onChange={this.onChangeCashSum}
                    placeholder="0.00"
                />
            </View>
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to only valid and update the value in your redux store when the user is finished editing vs on every keystroke. You might use the [`onEndEditing`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onendediting) `TextInput` callback to accomplish this.

Comment: I tried this approach and it works. But I don't like the fact that the user has to touch on any area of the screen so that his input is applied (for example, the total amount is recalculated)